# USB 3.0 ExternalEnclosure Unmounts at random

Tags: mount, hard-drive, power-management, raid, usb-drive

Title says it all.

I noticed the drive was unmounted, so I got to looking through dmesg and found:

```
[31080.516164] usb 4-3: USB disconnect, device number 3
[31080.760493] usb 4-3: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[31080.776291] usb 4-3: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[31080.776753] usb 4-3: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=0539
[31080.776760] usb 4-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=10, Product=11, SerialNumber=5
[31080.776767] usb 4-3: Product: USB to ATA/ATAPI Bridge
[31080.776772] usb 4-3: Manufacturer: JMicron
[31080.776778] usb 4-3: SerialNumber: 000000000000
[31080.777533] usb-storage 4-3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[31080.777785] scsi8 : usb-storage 4-3:1.0
[31083.794440] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     JMB352   RAID-1           0X01 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[31083.795170] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[31095.915699] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Spinning up disk...
[31096.924039] .ready
[31096.924379] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] 3907028992 512-byte logical blocks: (2.00 TB/1.81 TiB)
[31096.924907] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
[31096.924915] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 27 00 00 00
[31096.925445] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[31096.925452] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[31096.927083] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[31096.927090] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[31097.006510]  sdc: sdc1
[31097.011577] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
[31097.011589] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
[31097.011612] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI disk
```

After a

```
mount -a
```

I found the following in dmesg

```
[31524.944795] usb 4-3: reset SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[31524.960309] usb 4-3: Parent hub missing LPM exit latency info.  Power management will be impacted.
[31524.960471] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004f139d80
[31524.960478] xhci_hcd 0000:04:00.0: xHCI xhci_drop_endpoint called with disabled ep ffff88004f139dc0
[31525.813172] EXT4-fs (sdc1): recovery complete
[31525.813499] EXT4-fs (sdc1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
```

Also, I've written a cron script to write to the external box every second (just with touch) because I couldn't make power management not spin down the disks.  Which lines up with what the dmesg output is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!